# SQL Filter rows if condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run a query that will filter the rows by this expression (If instance name LIKE '1 %' then remove all the rows that has the same EntityKeyID) 
I removed some columns on the example no place for them

```
    SELECT  
       EntityKeyID
      ,[StatusTypeID]
      ,[InternalNote]
      ,[InstanceName]
      ,[DateRequired]
      ,[LinkName]
      ,[VendorName]
  FROM [ASTRO].[dbo].[vw_EntityServices_Legs]
where  (SELECT statustypeID from vw_EntityServices_Legs where InstanceName LIKE '1 %') NOT IN InstanceName
```

[image: **Table that i want to create the query**]

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE` clause you have; apart from that you are using an `IN` with one value and without any parenthesis (`()`). It should either be `NOT IN (InstanceName)` or `!= InstanceName`. (I suggest the latter if you're only ever going to be supplying one value).

Comment: i was testing different things i forgot the comment in and i tried that way doesn't works

Comment: Shouldn't it be instancename not in (select )?

Comment: Why a reference to statustypeID if you want to filter on EntityKeyID.  Question is not clear to me.

Comment: "i tried that way doesn't works". Why? An error, unexpected behaviour, a Monkey jumps out of the SQL Server and quietly says "Access denied" before climbing back in? :) Please elaborate; provide details/the error/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your words

> If instance name LIKE '1 %' then remove all the rows that has the same
>   EntityKeyID

```
where EntityKeyID not in ( select nl.EntityKeyID 
                           from vw_EntityServices_Legs nl 
                           where nl.InstanceName LIKE '1 %'
                         )
```